# HTML Textarea CSS Not Allowing Other CSS

Tags: html, css

In my CSS file, I have

```
textarea {
    vertical-align: top;
}​
table, tr, td, thead, tfoot, colgroup, col, caption {
    margin: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
table {
    width: 90%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
}
```

but the part directly below the

```
textarea {
    vertical-align: top;
}​
```

always gets ignored, no matter the order. Also, if I put the textarea CSS at the bottom of my CSS file, that gets ignored. Does anybody know how to fix this? My CSS was working   before I added the textarea part

Comment: Are you missing any `}` in your file?

Comment: give your all html and css code

Comment: Inspect the browser and find if any css override the property. or use !important in it.

Comment: How about adding it to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to see?

Comment: @Mooseman I am not missing any `}`

Comment: @anni, the problem was in just the textarea CSS

Comment: To everybody, thanks for your help, but I got it fixed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add vertical-align to your child element. Your table column determines where its child elements sit.

CSS:

```
td.textarea {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}​
table, tr, td, thead, tfoot, colgroup, col, caption {
    margin: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
table {
    width: 90%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
}
```

See this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/chtna) example for the live example.